# NRPE check undefined ...but why?

Tags: nagios, cassandra-2.0, nrpe

I've got two NRPE checks in nagios that are failing as undefined in the nagios web interface.

[image: NRPE Not Defined Error]

Which is odd, because:

1)  I have the check defined in the config file for this host on the nagios server. In /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/web2.cfg I have these two definitions.

```
# Define a service to check Cassandra reads on the web2 machine.
define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       web2
        service_description             Check NRPE Cassandra JMX
        contact_groups                  linux-admins
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_cassandra_jmx
        notifications_enabled           1
      }

# Define a service to check Cassandra reads on the web2 machine.
    define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       web2
        service_description             Check NRPE Cassandra Heap
        contact_groups                  linux-admins
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_cassandra_heap
        notifications_enabled           1
      }
```

2) I have the check defined in the nrpe.cfg on the host I'm checking:

```
[root@web2:~] #egrep "heap|jmx" /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg
command[check_cassandra_jmx]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_jmx -U     service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://beta.jokefire.com:7199/jmxrmi -O     java.lang:type=Memory -A HeapMemoryUsage -K used -I HeapMemoryUsage -J used -vvvv     -w 10737418240 -c 20401094656
command[check_cassandra_heap]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/cassandra.pl
```

3) If I go back to the nagios host and run the commands via check_nrpe on the command line, it succeeds:

```
[root@monitor1:~] #/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H web2.mydomain.com -c check_cassandra_jmx
JMX OK     HeapMemoryUsage.used=142913536{committed=526385152;init=536870912;max=526385152;u    sed=142913536}

[root@monitor1:~] #/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H web2.mydomain.com -c check_cassandra_heap
CASSANDRA OK -  | heap_mem=27.46
```

Other checks for this host are working fine in the web interface. Does anyone out there have some ideas about what's wrong in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: What does it say in your nagios logs more specifically for the check?

Comment: Did you bounce nrpe after you changed nrpe.cfg?

Comment: Yep!  I bounced nagios after making the change. Also I don't see any log entries pertaining to these errors. I was grepping through syslog (/var/log/messages) but couldn't find anything.